# How to change only one column of all excel files in the folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have 50 .xlsx or .csv files in a folder. I want to change the data specific to a header "PlantNo" with new data.

Suppose old data was "35" and now I want to replace that with "1" for all the excel workbooks in the folder for the specific column and not for whole data.

I have already written code which will change all This to That but I want this to be restricted to only one column

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

In response to the question you could use something like this:

```
Sub sbOneColumnReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable flicker on screen
Dim lLastCol As Long, lNumCol As Long, lLastRow As Long
Dim sTitleCol As String
Dim wsThis As Worksheet

'Here add/define the workbook

Set wsThis = Worksheets(1) 'Select first sheet
lLastCol = wsThis.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Last column in a specific row

For lNumCol = 1 To lLastCol 'Loop from the first column to the last one found
    sTitleCol = wsThis.Cells(1, lNumCol).Value 'I suppose the Title is in the first row, if not change the number value

    If sTitleCol = "PlantNo" Then 'This search the title vlaue.If you want it, you could use also vLookup with the defined range


        wsThis.Columns(lNumCol).Replace _
        What:="35", Replacement:="1", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

    End If

Next lNumCol
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Untested**
But its important to note that may be better/different ways to achive it, and as @Katz mention is important to add code or reference to show you have already search an approach to your problem and reflex that you investigate about it, and the reinforce/correction of that knowledge may come, and if you only post the question without any of these, sometimes (if not always) it'll be skipped by everyone (Belive me, Im a newbie here too). Hope it helps you in the right direction